# How to add outlined material icon in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using android material icon plugin, nut in that no option for 'outlined icon', any options or any other plugin?

Currently I am using - https://github.com/konifar/android-material-design-icon-generator-plugin

Comment: I've cloned this plugin and added new features and fixes. Do checkout.

[https://github.com/Dhaval2404/material-icon-generator-plugin](https://github.com/Dhaval2404/material-icon-generator-plugin)