# How can I use outlined Material icons in Android Studio?

Tags: android, google-material-icons

I would like to use outlined Material icons in my Android Studio project but I'm not able to find how. I've searched on Google similar questions and only found [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55020817/how-to-add-outlined-material-icon-in-android-studio). I've also searched on the Material Design website, but the "copy" icon doesn't appears in it...

So, how can I use outlined Material icons ?

Comment: The simple way is download icons that you want and add one by one using **Vector Assets**

Comment: https://material.io/resources/icons/?search=copy&style=outline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can switch to outlined icons in the drop down menu.

[image: Vector assets]

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the res > drawable folder in the Explorer area on the left of Android Studio. From the menu that appears, select New > Vector Asset